# Using Kafka to import data to Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, flume, apache-kafka

Firstly I was thinking what to use to get events into Hadoop, where they will be stored and periodically analysis would be performed on them (possibly using Ooozie to schedule periodic analysis) Kafka or Flume, and decided that Kafka is probably a better solution, since we also have a component that does event processing, so in this way, both batch and event processing components get data in the same way.

But know I'm looking for suggestions concretely how to get data out of broker to Hadoop.

I found [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Ecosystem) that Flume can be used in combination with Kafka

- Flume - Contains Kafka Source (consumer) and Sink (producer)

And also found on the same page and in [Kafka documentation](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#introduction) that there is something called [Camus](https://github.com/linkedin/camus)

- Camus - LinkedIn's Kafka=>HDFS pipeline. This one is used for all data at LinkedIn, and works great.

I'm interested in what would be a better (and easier, better documented solution) to do that? Also, are there any examples or tutorials how to do it?

When should I use this variants over simpler, *High level consumer*?

I'm opened for suggestions if there is another/better solution than this two.

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at this video from the latest Kafka user group meetup for some tips: http://www.hakkalabs.co/articles/kafka-hadoop-2

Comment: Thanks, this is a great video. If you have some concrete tutorials perhaps it would be great.

Comment: @abeaamase thanks for your answer, but your link seems to be broken?

Comment: Check out: http://ingest.tips/2014/09/26/trying-to-decide-between-flume-and-kafka-try-both/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use flume to dump data from Kafka to HDFS. Flume has kafka source and sink. Its a matter of property file change. An example is given below.

Steps:

1. Create a kafka topic

   ```
   kafka-topics --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --     partitions 1 --topic testkafka
   ```
2. Write to the above created topic using kafka console producer

   ```
   kafka-console-producer --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic testkafka
   ```
3. Configure a flume agent with the following properties

   ```
   flume1.sources  = kafka-source-1
   flume1.channels = hdfs-channel-1
   flume1.sinks    = hdfs-sink-1
   flume1.sources.kafka-source-1.type = org.apache.flume.source.kafka.KafkaSource
   flume1.sources.kafka-source-1.zookeeperConnect = localhost:2181
   flume1.sources.kafka-source-1.topic =testkafka
   flume1.sources.kafka-source-1.batchSize = 100
   flume1.sources.kafka-source-1.channels = hdfs-channel-1

   flume1.channels.hdfs-channel-1.type   = memory
   flume1.sinks.hdfs-sink-1.channel = hdfs-channel-1
   flume1.sinks.hdfs-sink-1.type = hdfs
   flume1.sinks.hdfs-sink-1.hdfs.writeFormat = Text
   flume1.sinks.hdfs-sink-1.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
   flume1.sinks.hdfs-sink-1.hdfs.filePrefix = test-events
   flume1.sinks.hdfs-sink-1.hdfs.useLocalTimeStamp = true
   flume1.sinks.hdfs-sink-1.hdfs.path = /tmp/kafka/%{topic}/%y-%m-%d
   flume1.sinks.hdfs-sink-1.hdfs.rollCount=100
   flume1.sinks.hdfs-sink-1.hdfs.rollSize=0
   flume1.channels.hdfs-channel-1.capacity = 10000
   flume1.channels.hdfs-channel-1.transactionCapacity = 1000
   ```

Save the above config file as example.conf

4. Run the flume agent

   ```
   flume-ng agent -n flume1 -c conf -f example.conf -    Dflume.root.logger=INFO,console
   ```

Data will be now dumped to HDFS location under the following path

```
/tmp/kafka/%{topic}/%y-%m-%d
```

Comment: The topic chunk is filled with an empty value in the destination path, at least in  my case... the official flume documentation does not list the "topic" scape sequence. Did you tried it? I need it working. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, I see people using Camus with azkaban

You can you at the github repo of Mate1 for their implementation of Camus. It's not a tutorial but I think it could help you

https://github.com/mate1/camus